# Scripts are not running in parallel, its running in sequence

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot I started the script at 09:55:31, script a.sh finished its execution at 09:55:36 and b.sh started at 09:55:36 (after the execution of a.sh) and finished at 09:55:38. If you have noticed it is running in sequence, according to me b.sh was suppose to start its execution at 09:55:31 why isnt it running in parallel?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `parallel` command but after reading [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) I'd say you are launching **just** one script because the key separator `--` is not present.

Comment: What is the output of `parallel --number-of-cores`?

Comment: @Jdamian you are linking to Tollef's Parallel - not GNU Parallel. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Comment: 4 cores @OleTange

Comment: You may have found a bug. Please follow https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#REPORTING-BUGS (the error is dependent on your environment or distribution)

Comment: Hi @OleTange, I used the virtual machine which you had proposed (http://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/) . But still the scripts are running in sequence.

Comment: Osboxes has many machines. Which one of them did you use?

Comment: Virtual box @OleTange

Comment: @OleTange, Thank you for your info. @SummanNagaraj, I apologize for misleading... I'm not familiar with `parallel`.

Comment: @SumanNagaraj You have to be more specific if you want any help. Which OS? Which version? Which architecture? You will make it easier if you provide a direct link to the file you downloaded.

Comment: http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/ (Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety yak 64bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now:

- downloaded https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HAFnYs6Ur-TVdfcHBrUVRWQk0/view?usp=sharing
- configured it with network
- configured it with 4 CPUs running at 100%
- typed in the script you use (You could have helped by putting it as text in your question so I would have been able to simply copy it)

I get:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ parallel --number-of-cores
4
osboxes@osboxes:~$ time bash test.sh 
[ OK ] b.sh
Sat Feb 11 15:41:34 GMT 2017
Pass b.sh
[ OK ] a.sh
Sat Feb 11 15:41:37 GMT 2017
Pass a.sh

real    0m5.185s
user    0m0.152s
sys     0m0.032s
```

which is exactly what I would expect.

This leads me to believe you are doing something you are not telling us.

Are you somehow setting `--jobs 1` for `parallel`?

Comment: Hi , I used `parallel --joblog log.txt tester bash :::: sample.txt` to generate a log file, though the script fails the exit value is still zero in log file.